# .htacces file not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm using XAMPP local host server. I'm creating a simple REST API which works fine on my local host with the `.htaccess` code below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]   
</IfModule>
```

My local folder name is `gem_api`, located in `C:\xampp\htdocs\gem_api` and it is working.

But, when I used the same `.htaccess` code on a server I didn't receive a response.
On the server my project is in `/var/www/develoer.gemtravels.com/public_html`

What should change in my `.htaccess` file so that it will work on the server too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the use of htaccess files [allowed](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles) on your hosting? Check apache error log for confirmation.

Comment: Thanks for giving hint to me. Yes there is problem with server. It not allow me. I concern with admin and issue solve Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the use of [htaccess files allowed](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles) on your hosting? Check Apache error log for confirmation.

*Duplicated from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36151816/htacces-file-not-working/36174527#comment59940886_36151816) above.*

Answer (score 0):

In your **`Httpd.conf`** file search the keyword **`AllowOverride` and check that it is set to `All` instead of `None`** for the desired directory entry:

```
<Directory />
    # ...
    AllowOverride All
    # ...
</Directory>
```